# Mockito - Mocking overloaded methods with Varargs parameters

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Mockito is hard to use when we need to mock overloaded methods when one of them is using varargs. Consider the below methods from Spring's `RestTemplate`

```
void put(String url, Object request, Object... uriVariables) throws RestClientException;

void put(String url, Object request, Map<String, ?> uriVariables) throws RestClientException;
```

Mocking the second one is straight forward, but mocking the first one is not possible as using `any()` would result in an ambiguous method call matching both the methods and there is no alternative to match just `Object...`

Sharing the solution as Q & A that I arrived after putting some effort so as to help those in the same boat. All other alternatives welcome.

Comment: What Mockito version are you using?

Comment: Its 2.21.0 which was used when the project was created, but looking at the latest documentation, the case still looks the same. https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.25.1/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution to this can be attempted by making use of the feature to provide a `defaultAnswer` to the mock. The defaultAnswer will evaluate that the invocation is for the specific method and perform the needed action, and let the invocation follow the natural flow if the required method is not targeted.

This can be explained well with an example. Consider the two overloaded methods in the class below:

```
public class StringConcat {
    public String concatenate(int i, String... strings) {
        return i + Arrays.stream(strings).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    }

    public String concatenate(int i, List<String> strings) {
        return i + strings.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    }
}
```

The second method can be mocked using Mockito like below:

```
StringConcat stringConcat = mock(StringConcat.class);
when(stringConcat.concatenate(anyInt(), anyList())).thenReturn("hardcoded value");
```

To represent varargs, we do not have `anyVararg()` method (deprecated and does not work, not sure if it worked in older versions). But the same can be handled by creating the mock with defaultAnswer like below:

```
@Test
void testWithDefaultAnswer(){
    // Creating mock object with default answer
    StringConcat stringConcat = mock(StringConcat.class, invocation -> {
        Method method = invocation.getMethod();
        if (method.getName().contains("concatenate") && 
               method.getParameters()[method.getParameters().length-1].isVarArgs()){
            if(invocation.getArguments().length>=method.getParameterCount()){
                List varArgParams = Arrays.stream(invocation.getArguments())
                          .skip(method.getParameterCount()-1)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
                return invocation.getArguments()[0]+":"
                      +varArgParams.toString(); // mocked result when varargs provided
            }
            return ""+invocation.getArguments()[0]; // mocked result when varargs not provided
        }
        return Answers.RETURNS_DEFAULTS.answer(invocation); // Ensures seamless mocking of any other methods
    });

    // Mock any non varargs methods as needed
    when(stringConcat.concatenate(anyInt(), anyList())).thenReturn("hardcoded"); // mocking as usual

    // Test the mocks
    System.out.println(stringConcat.concatenate(1, "a", "b")); // default answer based mock, with varargs provided
    System.out.println(stringConcat.concatenate(1)); // default answer based mock, without varargs provided
    System.out.println(stringConcat.concatenate(1, Lists.newArrayList("a", "b"))); // mocked non varargs method
}
```

Output:

```
1:[a, b]
1
hardcoded
```